# What is the difference between SBT and IDEA when creating a Scala project in intelliJ?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

When creting a project in IntelliJ, I am given options for sbt, Lightbend Project Starter, IDEA, Play 2.x, Dotty(experimental). What do these options mean, and how could I learn more about them?

Comment: Intellij is an IDE and SBT is a build tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDEA project, is just IDE configuration that let's you work with Scala... but it doesn't come with build system that you can easily configure, commit to git repo, etc - you basically would have to configure everything in IntelliJ yourself which is a pain.

Other options are [sbt](https://www.scala-sbt.org/) templates where sbt is a build tool for Scala:

- sbt - creates empty build configuration and imports it to IDE
- Lightbend Project Starter - a collection of templates with configurations seeded. In general `sbt new template-name` can [generate a project](http://www.foundweekends.org/giter8/) using template name (github repository name of a template) and Lightbend  prepared and maintains some of them
- Play - sbt configurations for [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/)
- Dotty - sbt configuration for [Dotty (experimiental Scala 3)](https://dotty.epfl.ch/)

With them you have a build config that you can configure and import and check into git, that is used by IntelliJ to generate IDE configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> IDEA is something related to IntelliJ IDE. 
>   SBT is a build tool(substitute for maven) for scala projects.
>   When you enable SBT option, it will add sbt related configuration, sbt shell, sbt options. You can choose sbt if your project is built upon sbt (means your project will have a build.sbt file).
>
> The other options also can be opted only if your project folder demands it.

Answer (score 0):

Dotty is the name of the future version of the language (Scala 3). See https://dotty.epfl.ch/.